# How can I query JSON records in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm calling a REST api in PowerShell and it is returning some JSON

```
$records = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Headers $headers
```

If I use the `.data` attribute, I'm getting what I assume is a PowerShell array object, because I can examine `$records.data.count` and I get the expected number of records.  Examining one of those records, eg `$records.data[5]`

```
id            : 123
zone_id       : example.com
parent_id     : 
name          : z1
content       : 1.2.3.4
ttl           : 3600
priority      : 
type          : A
regions       : {global}
system_record : False
created_at    : 2015-01-10T02:33:46Z
updated_at    : 2015-01-10T02:33:46Z
```

I want to get all of the records where **type** is **A**.  I've tried `$records.data.Where($_.type -eq 'A')` but that is giving me a type exception.  What query should I use to filter based upon attribute values?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried `$records.data.Where($_.type -eq 'A')` but that is giving me a type exception.

The `Where()` extension method takes a `ScriptBlock` as its first argument (notice the curly braces):

```
$records.data.Where({$_.type -eq 'A'})
```